# Does the Vedic Sanatana dharma endorse the view that a cow deserves to be worshipped as the mother of humanity?

Tags: scripture, vedas, rig-veda, cows, human

I've heard by the Vedic view, the birth as a human follows numerous births as beasts. A cow is a beast. Can a cow deserve the respect as the Mother of humanity? What's the True Vedic stance on this issue? Curious to know!